# dnet: Failed to open device wlan0

Tags: networking, ubuntu-mate

I'm running the latest version of MATE on a raspberry pi 3B+. Nmap works fine on a standard account, but I want to use the `-O` param, which requires root privs. 
i ran `nmap 192.168.1.0/24 -p 22,80,443 -O`, and it returned an error `dnet: Failed to open device wlan0`, which is strange, since it seemed to work fine without root privs.

Comment: The wireless device may be named in systemd way - check `ls /sys/class/net/`.

Comment: `ls /sys/class/net` returns it as wlan0. Could it be driver related?